# Access Transparency Permission for my app on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am unable to enable access transparency for my organization having an app on Google cloud. Tried various things but nothing worked. Following is what I am getting always.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91kT2.jpg)

We tried to follow checklist given by google cloud "Manage Google Cloud setup for your organization" but could not finish all 10 steps required because of need for some networking entry.